# How to insert multiple values in single column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've created two simple tables in phpmyadmin. A list of "content creators" and a list of "content creator types". Each "content creator" can have multiple "content creator types" associated with them so this is a one-many relationship. In phpmyadmin I created the following relationship.

```
ALTER TABLE  `contentcreator` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `ContCreat_TypeID` ) 
  REFERENCES `MyDatabase`.`contentcreator_types` (`ContCreat_TypeID`) 
  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;
```

Now when I try to insert data (using the insert data interface in phpmyadmin) into the table "content creator" - I get a drop down to allow me to choose one of "content creator type IDs". However I want to be able to add multiple "content creator type IDs" to each content creator. How do I do this within phpmyadmin using the insert data interface?

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a many to many relationship?  A creator can have many types, and a type can be on many creators

Comment: It's actually a Many-to-Many relationship. You'll need a third table that has FK references to both your content creators table's PK and your content creator types table's PK. This is often called a Junction or a Join table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I will create a junction table as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a many to many relationship here, not a one to many.  You need to add an intersection table with foreign keys to both your types table, and your content creators table.

If you wanted to do this as a one to many relationship, the side that is many gets the foreign key, not the side that is one.  Meaning you would have a foreign key to the content Creators table on the content creators type table.  Then each content creator would get a new entry in the type table for each type that it had, however you would have duplication in that scenario.

Many TO Many:

```
ContentCreatorID CreatorName
---------------- ------------------
1                Creator1
2                Creator2
3                Creator3

CreatorTypes (intersection Table)


ContentCreatorID TypeID
---------------- ------------------
1                1
1                2
2                3
3                2


Types

TypeID            TypeName
---------------- ------------------
1                 Type1
2                 Type2
3                 Type3
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I will add the intersection table as suggested to connect the two.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider creating a mapping table to associate creators with their types

```
    creator table
    id | creator

    type table
    id | type

    mapping table
    creator_id | type_id
```